SEO-Friendly: Legacy SSR vs. Using SPA Frameworks
I'm developing a web application with a C# .NET core backend and am seeking insights into the SEO implications of choosing between legacy server-side rendering (SSR) and modern single-page application (SPA) frameworks like Blazor, React, Vue.js or others.
The question is: does it worth using an SPA framework (even with SSR techniques) for an SEO-focused project? Specifically, I'm interested in the SEO impact in terms of crawlability, indexing, and overall performance.
Please share any relevant experiences, case studies, or performance data to support your recommendations.
Thank you!

Server side rendering isn't particularly a legacy approach - most of the web is still built on that (this site claims that 43% of the web is Wordpress, for example), and it's great for your static website, blog etc.
The strength of React etc is if you've got a lot of live data and/or are building a Progressive Web App instead of a static website, in which case it can handle that with less risk of spaghetti code.  Such libraries don't tend to describe themselves as a modern approach to development, but instead React is described as "for web and native user interfaces" - it was designed with a specific type of build in mind.  In React's case, to build Facebook's feed.
In my experience, it's a lot easier to make static websites run fast and write clean, optimised, semantic HTML using SSR.  However, it's still possible to build an SEO friendly site using a javascript library - you just tend to spend a lot more time fiddling with Google Lighthouse to get the scores up.
Both approaches are fine for SEO if you understand SEO and how to write semantic HTML, so I'd argue it would depend what your project is and picking the right tool for your project's overall purpose and ease of development.
Any SEO problems are going to be down to how it's developed and the HTML it outputs, not what it's been developed with (with the possible exception that some javascript libraries are slowwwwwwww).

Thanks @RichardB for your answer. By "legacy SSR," I mean using SSR without any modern JS frameworks. The project is an informational website where users can see certain places on a map, write comments, and share their thoughts. They may also want to buy some things on the website, but in this case they can be redirected to a new section of the website if they choose to make a purchase, and there, we can use a library like react or vue.js. In conclusion, would it be accurate to say that for this type of website, it's preferable to utilize SSR without any JS framework and client-side rendering?

If it's going to be a single page with lots of javascript, then I'd say look at js frameworks  - that's what they're for.  If it's several pages and mostly static HTML then go the SSR route.  If it's SEO-focussed, I'd assume you'll be wanting several pages so that you can capture more keywords.

I've not used it personally, but htmx looks a nice middle ground for some situations - I like the clean code, unlike html-in-js solutions.

Thanks a lot @RechardB, your assistance means a lot!
